# Why is the program not showing any AssertionError?

Tags: java, assertion

I have executed the code like this : java -ea HelloWorld and for other codes the AssertionError is showing but, for this particular code I am not getting any AssertionError.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         boolean b=true;
         assert(b==true);
         b=false;     
     }
}
```

Comment: The assert only applies to the condition at the point in the code where the assert is placed. Changing the value being asserted *after* the `assert` statement does not re-apply the assertion check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asserting that `b==true`, which it does at the time the assertion executes. If the assertion is false, `AssertionError` is thrown.  From the [Oracle documentation:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)

> Each assertion contains a boolean expression that you believe will be
>   true when the assertion executes. If it is not true, the system will
>   throw an error. By verifying that the boolean expression is indeed
>   true, the assertion confirms your assumptions about the behavior of
>   your program, increasing your confidence that the program is free of
>   errors

And it can be applied in 2 different ways:

> The assertion statement has two forms. The first, simpler form is:
>
> `assert` *Expression1* ;
>
> where *Expression1* is a `boolean` expression. When
>   the system runs the assertion, it evaluates *Expression1* and if it is
>   `false` throws an `AssertionError` with no detail message.
>
> The second form of the assertion statement is:
>
> `assert` *Expression1* : *Expression2* ;
>
> where:
>
> - *Expression1* is a `boolean` expression.
> - *Expression2* is an expression that has a value. (It cannot be an invocation of a method that is declared void.)
>
> Use this version of the `assert` statement to provide a detail message for the `AssertionError`. The system passes the value of *Expression2* to the appropriate `AssertionError` constructor, which uses the string representation of the value as the error's detail message.

Comment: What I understand of assert is it says for example if I write assert(x>5), then if anywhere in the program if I assign x=4 assertion error is shown OR it says that x has to get a value greater than 5. Now, in the above code I apply the same logic assert(b==true). So, if now in the code I reassign the value of b as NOT true it should throw an AssertionError.

Comment: @SamarthMishra Read the Oracle documentation I linked to. It says that **Each assertion contains a boolean expression that you believe will be true when the assertion executes.**. It doesn't put in a system wide assertion of a value. It is evaluated like other code.

Comment: @SamarthMishra if this answers your question then please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you haven't figured out how Java assertion works:

assert *expression* : *message_if_not_true*

Therefore, if your assertion evaluates as False, you will get an error message.

What you are doing:

```
assert(b == true)
```

will not cause assertionError because b is set to true on the previous line. Check Java Oracle documentation for assertions.

Comment: Thanks I had already cleared! But, thanks once again